# JavaScript Array not showing all output values in terminal

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to run a simple node.js file in my terminal.

```
let num = []

while(num.length <= 10000) {
    var r = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10001);
    num.push(r);
}

console.log(num)
```

It works as intended but the output is returned like this:

```
[
  5238, 6159, 5080, 7189, 6271, 9754, 1046, 7335, 8681, 8641,
  9828, 4525, 4531, 6750, 9403, 5153, 3421, 5207, 9250, 9749,
  7627,  402, 4018, 6458, 4135, 2610, 2981, 3325, 9675, 2068,
  1423, 8946,  146, 6731, 9955, 8821,   40, 2923, 8300, 2290,
   893, 4681, 9067, 8802, 1345, 1511, 2270, 9911, 5231, 1048,
  3837, 1008, 9509, 9300, 5017, 4697,   50, 4366, 9309,  211,
  2074, 6414,  150, 1042, 9763, 5458, 7697, 1773, 6728, 1177,
  4126, 1608, 2300, 6781, 9520, 4113, 9326, 8839, 3047, 5952,
  2943, 9263, 9834, 5714, 3903, 8526, 7211, 3937, 9925, 8609,
  4756, 6822, 6010, 8784, 5828, 1181, 3231, 9680, 2506, 4391,
  ... 9901 more items
]
```

I would like to be able to see all the values and not the '… 9901 more items' does anyone know how to change this behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```js
console.log(...num)
```